# Various IPs unaccessible after connection to new WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, http

since I've connected to my parents' wireless network, there are several programs that stopped working on any network connection (even mine, even though they used to work on that before). Examples are:

- League of Legends (RADS HTTP error)
- AVG Updater ("Authentication is
  needed to access updates")
- Steam ("Could not connect to Steam
  network")
- EVE Online ("Remote Info-file could not be fetched")

These programs worked for me before on both WiFi and Hotspot.

I can access most of the required files these programs need in my browsers (IE and Chrome).

My parents have a BT Home Hub 4 router, that's about as much as I know about it.

Comment: They no longer work on any network or just your parent's network?

Comment: On any network. Tried my home wifi, and my phone's hotspot.